# How to display a webpage from a python program?

Tags: python

I've got a list of webpages that I need to categorise so I'm trying to write a script in python that will display the webpage and then depending on a key press it will save the url of that webpage to a different file depending on the key.

However I'm not sure what would be the easiest way to display the webpages from the urls I've got?

Thanks

Comment: What you mean saying display the webpage? To display it like browser does or you need screen shot or what?

Comment: I need to open it in a browser but I need to be able to close the browser from the program as theres a couple of thousand urls in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The [webbrowser module](http://pymotw.com/2/webbrowser/) will allow you to open HTML files in your browser from Python, but I'm not sure if you'd still be able to manipulate the program from there. Intuition tells me that that would be impossible (or at least stupendously difficult) without making your own entire browser in Python.

Comment: Thats what I've been trying to use at the minute but I can't seem to close the browser windows without using os.kill